# Office.js Excel: deselect current selection?

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

In [the Office.js API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range) I see a `Range.select()` method, but **is there anyway to deselect whatever is currently selected on the spreadsheet?**

My add-in has an onSelectionChanged listener which listens for when a cell is selected and reacts accordingly. However, if a cell is selected first, then my add-in is launched, and then they click again on the same cell that was already selected, nothing happens (because the selection didn't change).

Thus, when my add-in is launched, I'd like to clear all selections so it will behave accordingly when the user makes *any* selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, there is always a selected cell.

You're best bet then is to reset their selection `A1`. This doesn't completely resolve the issue but does reduce the chances of a user running into it. The assumption being that A1 is less likely to contain something the user wants to look up (i.e. it's almost always a label).